# How to make python look hex numbers as two's complemented?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers, twos-complement

I have an array of hex positive and negetive numbers. I want to transform them to decimal value:

```
>>> int("f107",16)
61703
>>>
```

how can I make python to look `f107` as a two's complemented number? In the other word I want `-3833` instead of `61703`. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very simple function:

```
def twos_complement(n, w):
    if n & (1 << (w - 1)): n = n - (1 << w)
    return n
```

Example:

```
>>> twos_complement(61703, 16)
-3833
```

Unlike Joran's answer this supports arbitrary bit-width.

Comment: great answer :) although you still have to pass in the width(I think you could calculate it with logs and stuff) ...  but its cool that you could use weird non standard widths

Comment: If your function took the "f107" hex string as its arg it could calculate the required width of the bitmask...

Comment: @JoranBeasley You can't calculate the width. Compare `twos_complement(5, 3)` with `twos_complement(5, 4)`. One is simply 5, but in the other width's it's -3. You have to give the width explicitly to interpret numbers as two's complement.

Comment: @PM2Ring You can build that function using this one, but not the other way around :) This is more general.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Excuse me I didn't got the point about `width`. May I ask to explain a little more?(_have to pass in the width_)

Comment: @Abraham A two's complement number has a width. For example a 32-bit number, or a 16-bit number. The number you gave in your question is a 16-bit number. The actual value of the number depends on the width.

Comment: @Abraham: It's a little tricky doing this stuff in Python. Unlike in C, where you have various fixed sized integers, Python's integers are of arbitrary size: they're as big as they need to be. So when you want to use some form of complement notation to represent negative quantities you need to specify the width.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct.unpack(">h","f107".decode("hex"))
```

`0xf107` = encode_to_bytes => `"\xf1\x07"`

since its two bytes we simply unpack it as `>` big-endian `h` signed-short